# how to show li tag based on index value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

i have a html like this,

```
  <div class="main">
     <ul>
         <li ng-repeat='save in saves'>
           <h3>{{save.name}}</h3>
           <div >
              <ul>
                <li ng-repeat='story in stories'>
                   <div  ng-show="story.display"><label>welcome</label></div>
                   <div  ng-show="!story.display"><input type="text"></div>
                </li>
              </ul>
           </div>
            <div ng-click="add()">Click</div>
         </li>
     </ul>
     <div ng-click="theme()">Add theme</div>
  </div>
```

my contoller like this

```
       $scope.saves=[];
       $scope.stories=[];
       $scope.theme=function()
      {
         $scope.saves.push({name:'joseph',name:'john',name'peter'});
      };
      $scope.add=function()
      {
        $scope.stories.push({display:'false'});
      };
```

Here i am doing this ,

When user click on addtheme button i am pushing name into saves (Array) and then repeating it with li tag so out put like this

```
  joseph

  click

  john

  click

  peter 

  click
```

so when again user click on click , i want to show only one textbox for  specific clicked  li..but here what happened , when i click on click button it is showing three text box for three li tag....

How to open specific textbox?

Answer (score 0):

your can replace

```
<div  ng-show="!story.display"><input type="text"></div>
```

to

```
<div  ng-hide="story.display"><input type="text"></div>
```

Comment: if you use ng-show='!storey.display' the input box can not displayed.so you can use ng-hide try it.

Comment: even if i use ng-hide it will show textbox but not only one ,it will show all textbox....so how to show specific text box ?